# How to limit width of Text in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, layout, swiftui, frame

I was trying to make a speech bubble like so:

```
Text("Hello my name is Johnny Miller and I am new here")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding()
    .background(.blue)
    .cornerRadius(25)
```

However I thought the speech bubble looked way wider than it needed to be. Therefore I tried to limit how far out the bubble can stretch before it goes to a new line. The easiest way which came to mind was this:

```
Text("Hello my name is Johnny Miller and I am new here")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding()
    .background(.blue)
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .frame(maxWidth: 300)  // << Limits how wide it can stretch
```

This worked for long messages but when the text was small such as "Hello," the frame would stay at 300pts and refused to resize to its ideal width.

[image: Frame staying at 300pts]

I tried using `.fixedSize()` but this would cause truncation when the text was long.

I couldn't find a way to cap the width of the text and still have it be its ideal size. If someone could propose a solution I would be extremely grateful.

*In short: The text frame should never cross 300pts in width but it can be as tall as it wants.*

Thanks in advance!

#### Edit

These are the things I've tried so far:

```
Text("Hello")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding()
    .background(.blue)
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .frame(maxWidth: 300)
    .lineLimit(nil)
```

which causes the "Hello" bubble to have a frame of 300 (I've provided an image above)

and I've tried:

```
Text("Hello my name is Johnny Miller and I am new here")
    .foregroundColor(.white)
    .padding()
    .background(.blue)
    .cornerRadius(25)
    .frame(maxWidth: 300)
    .lineLimit(nil)
    .fixedSize()
```

which gave me:

[image: Truncated text]

Comment: The `maxWidth: 300` works fine both for long and short text. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1. Maybe your issue is in different code.

Comment: @Asperi I added a picture, did you get the same thing?

Comment: Same issue. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Same issue...surely there's a solution here...right?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Set the background of the Text view. Give the text view a maxWidth.

```
Text(message.content)
    .padding(.all,8)
    .background(Container()) // Container is a RoundedRectangle() with some styling
    .frame(maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

Gives you something  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPyWo.png)

**Explanation**

Text views in SwiftUI automatically resize themselves when needed.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0RtE.png)

You can set a maxWidth for your text using something like `.frame(maxWidth: 500)`

Since the text size already has the behavour that we want after setting a maxWidth, we can just give it a "container" by setting the background of the text to some view. You can also give it an alignment and padding to match the text bubble effect, or even a custom shape.

I just made a view called Container() which is just a RoundedRectangle() with styling.

```
struct Container: View {
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.container.opacity(1))
            .blendMode(.multiply)
            .shadow(color: .white.opacity(0.4), radius: 1, x: 0, y: 0)
            .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.1), radius: 4, x: 2, y: 4)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `UILabel` in this scenario. With `UILabel`, we can set `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` and also set the content hugging priority.

```swift
struct MaxWidthLabel: View {
    let text: String
    let textColor: Color
    let preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat

    init(_ text: String, textColor: Color, preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat) {
        self.text = text
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredMaxLayoutWidth
    }

    @Environment(\.lineLimit)
    private var lineLimit: Int?

    var body: some View {
        Label(
            text,
            lineLimit: lineLimit,
            textAlignment: .center,
            textColor: UIColor(textColor),
            preferredMaxLayoutWidth: preferredMaxLayoutWidth
        )
    }
}

private struct Label: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String
    let lineLimit: Int?
    let textAlignment: NSTextAlignment
    let textColor: UIColor?
    let preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat

    init(
        _ text: String,
        lineLimit: Int? = nil,
        textAlignment: NSTextAlignment,
        textColor: UIColor? = nil,
        preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat
    ) {
        self.text = text
        self.lineLimit = lineLimit
        self.textAlignment = textAlignment
        self.textColor = textColor
        self.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredMaxLayoutWidth
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Label>) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.numberOfLines = lineLimit ?? 0
        if let textColor = textColor {
            label.textColor = textColor
        }
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)

        updateUIView(label, context: context)
        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ label: UILabel, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<Label>) {
        let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphStyle.alignment = textAlignment

        let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text)
        attrString.addAttribute(
            NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle,
            value: paragraphStyle,
            range: NSRange(location: 0, length: attrString.length)
        )

        label.attributedText = attrString
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = preferredMaxLayoutWidth
    }
}
```

[image: short content]

[image: long content]